# Upload images and file extension missing on mysql field

Tags: php, image-uploading

I have this piece of code that executes a multi image upload and renaming it.

it works, The file is renamed correctly, but I do not understand why in the mysql database I do not have the file extension but only the name.

Example:
file name (folder): abcdefg.jpg

pd_image (mysql field): abcdefg

$resultname is the same for both

```
 $mainame = $handle->file_dst_name;


    $db_name = str_replace(" ","_",$mainame);
    $image = md5(rand() * time()) . ".$db_name";
    $parts = explode(".",$image);
    $extension = end($parts);
    $resultname = str_replace("." . $extension,"",$image);

         $handle->file_new_name_body   =   $resultname;
         $handle->image_resize     = true;
         $handle->image_ratio_crop = true;
         $handle->image_x          = 800;
         $handle->image_y          = 600;

        $handle->Process($dir_dest);

        // we check if everything went OK
        if ($handle->processed) {
              header("Location: index.php");    //echo 'image resized';
               $handle->clean();

    $query_img="INSERT into tbl_images (pd_id, file_name, pd_image) VALUES('$pd_id','$mainame','$resultname')";      
       $result2 = dbQuery($query_img);
```

I am using the class "class.upload.php"

Comment: It looks like you are removing (replacing) the extension yourself here: `$resultname = str_replace("." . $extension,"",$image);` In you have ANY errors, just debug them. Add loads of echos and var_dumps until you see where the extension vanishes. Dont just ask stackoverflow. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check this line, You are replacing the extension with the "".

```
$resultname = str_replace("." . $extension,"",$image);
```

Replace this line to

```
$resultname = $image.'.'.$extension;
```

your are giving variable $db_name as string.Correct way to concatenate the variable to another string is

```
 $image = md5(rand() * time()).$db_name;
```

Comment: correct, but the double-quoted string literal is just superfluous, it doesn't cause the issue at hand since php substitutes the variable. edit: and since apparently a dot is to be inserted between the randon value and the "name" part, using a double quoted string is probably just matter of opinion.

Comment: The issue is not there. and in any case the extension is still missing in the db. 
How is it possible that the file is renamed regularly but not in the db? the variable is the same: $resultname